# Airflow Task run delay as scheduled

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to set up an airflow cluster for recurrent job, for example hourly job run at the 5th mins in every hour. The job run but start time is always one hour later than its scheduled time (execution time).

```
dag = DAG(dag_id="dag_id",
          description=d'some jobs',
          schedule_interval="5 * * * *",
          default_args=default_args,
          start_date=datetime(2019, 7, 24), catchup=True)
```

Task Instance Attributes:

execution_date : 2019-08-08T16:05:00+00:00

start_date : 2019-08-08 17:05:19.007417+00:00

end_date : 2019-08-08 17:05:28.065114+00:00

Comment: This is expected behavior, I answered it here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404712/1451653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduler runs at the **end** of each period. The idea is that data for 5:05 to 6:05 cannot be processed until 6:05.

The best place I've seen this described is on a slideshow by one of the Airflow committers. See slides 11-13: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVN4HXtOC-HXvv00sEkoB90mxLDnCIKc/view

Comment: Thanks, I realized this assumption later. This slide is helpful too.