# Airflow Scheduling Monthly Jobs

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to schedule a monthly job which runs every month on the same day as of today. And i want first run to be today. For example today is 11/2 and time is 10am. How can i schedule a monthly job which runs every month on 2nd at 11 am, 11/2 has to be first run.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 11, 1,22,00),
    'email': "myemail@abc.com",
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
    'retries': 0
}   

def print_hello():
    today = date.today()
    print("Today's date:", today)
    return 'Hello world! Monthly Run'

dag = DAG('dummy_monthly', description='Simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='11 00 2 * *',
          start_date=datetime(2020, 11,2), catchup=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `schedule_interval` to `00 11 2 * *`

Comment: There was mistake i fixed the cron expression but still job is not running. My ask is if i want to schedule a monthly run effective from my current month. For example i want to schedule a monthly job to run on 11/18 as first run.

Comment: If you want your DAG to run at 11/18, set the start date to 11/17. Please refer to this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404712/7930151